# Have an iOS Simulator libSystem issue to run GH-Unit at command line

Tags: ios, unit-testing, travis-ci, gh-unit

Thank you for seeing this question.

I wrote unit tests with GHUnit.
Now I am trying build tests on terminal to connect with Travis CI, and facing a problem.

I basically followed
http://gabriel.github.io/gh-unit/docs/appledoc_include/guide_command_line.html
and customize a command little bit.

Here is customized command
`GHUNIT_CLI=1 xcodebuild ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -target UnitTest -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator build`

After that some compile started, but finally I got error below.
`The iOS Simulator libSystem was initialized out of order.  This is most often caused by running host executables or inserting host dylibs.  In the future, this will cause an abort.`

If you know the way to solve, please let me know that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, running it like this

```
GHUNIT_CLI=1 xcodebuild ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -workspace <yourworkspace> -scheme <scheme> -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator build
```

solved the problem